# Why does ACC Webhook API gives unexplanable error?

Tags: autodesk-forge

I faced 2 unexplainable errors when using Autodesk ACC Webhook API.

1. The event dm.version.deleted does not trigger when files are deleted from the folder which the webhook is subscribed to.
2. Even after successful 200 webhook response given to ACC, ACC still keeps sending me webhook notification.

Comment: Please make sure your webhook callback url is working by testing it in postman.

Comment: second question is not clear, can you please elaborate?